# in_array PHP Warning

Tags: php, object, in-array

**Necesito verificar si** a la hora de insertar un nuevo cliente, registrar.php, **existe el email** que se ha insertado en el formulario o no.

- Si existe, mensaje de alerta, manda el foco al campo input email y no
  envía datos.
- Si NO existe, lo insertamos en la base de datos al cliente.

**Función insertarCliente(...,...,...):**

```
    static public function insertarCliente($email, $nombre, $apellidos, $dni, $telefono, $password){
        $ejecucion = self::Conexion();
        $sql = "INSERT INTO clientes VALUES ('".$email."', '".$nombre."', '".$apellidos."', '".$dni."', '".$telefono."', '".$password."', 1)";
        $ok = $ejecucion->exec($sql);
        if($ok==1){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

**Función obtenerEmails():**

```
static public function obtenerEmails(){
    //Realizamos la consulta.
    $ejecucion = self::Conexion();
    $sql = "SELECT idemail FROM clientes;";
    $registro = $ejecucion->query($sql);
    //Creamos una array de emails.
    $emails = array();
    //Mientras haya email los guardamos...
    while($email = $registro->fetch()){
        //Array asociativo: al array $emails le pasamos el email concreto.
        array_push($emails, $email);
    }
    //Devolvemos el array de emails.
    return $emails;
}
```

**Código HTML/PHP:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Formulario de Registro</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos_registrar.css">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/validar_formulario.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body background="imagenes/fondo_campo2.jpg">
        <!--<h1>Formulario de Registro</h1>-->
        <form name="miformulario" id="miformulario" action="registrar.php" method="POST" class="form-register" onsubmit="return validar_formulario();">
            <h2 class="form-titulo">CREA UNA CUENTA</h2>
            <div class="contenedor-inputs">
                <!-- Por cada etiqueta de <input> <label for="id_mismo_que_input">XXXX: </label> -->             <!-- required para HTML5 -->
                <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" tabindex="1" class="input-2" onkeypress="return soloLetras(event);">
                <input type="text" name="apellidos" id="apellidos" placeholder="Apellidos" tabindex="2" class="input-2">
                <br/>
                <input type="text" name="idemail" id="email" placeholder="Email" tabindex="3" class="input-1">
                <br/>
                <input type="text" name="dni" id="dni" placeholder="DNI" maxlength="9" tabindex="4" class="input-2" onkeypress="return soloLetrasNumeros(event);">
                <input type="text" name="telefono" id="telefono" placeholder="Teléfono" maxlength="9" tabindex="5" class="input-2" onkeypress="return soloNumeros(event);">
                <br/>
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password1" placeholder="Contraseña" tabindex="6" class="input-2">
                <input type="password" name="password" id="password2" placeholder="Repetir contraseña" tabindex="7" class="input-2">
                <br/>
                <input type="submit" value="Registrar" name="registrar" class="registrar" tabindex="8"/>
                <?php
                include "Clases/BD.php";
                //Si pulsamos el botón "Registrar"...
                if(isset($_POST["registrar"])){
                    $nombre = $_POST["nombre"];
                    $apellidos = $_POST["apellidos"];
                    $dni = $_POST["dni"];
                    $telefono = $_POST["telefono"];
                    $idemail = $_POST["idemail"];
                    $password = $_POST["password"];

                    $idemails = BD::obtenerEmails();
                    if(!in_array($idemail, $idemails)){
                        //Llamamos al método "insertarCliente" y le pasamos los parámetros del formulario.
                        BD::insertarCliente($idemail, $nombre, $apellidos, $dni, $telefono, $password);
                        header ("Location: si.php");
                    }else{
                        header ("Location: no.php");
                    }
                }
                ?>
                <p class="form-link">¿Ya tienes una cuenta? <a href="iniciar_sesion_cliente.php">Ingresa aquí</a></p>
            </div>
        </form>
        <!--<div class="footer">
            <p>Copyrigth</p>
        </div>-->
    </body>
</html>
```

**Error:**

**¿Por qué siempre me entra en si.php exista o no exista el email en la BBDD?**

Comment: El segundo parámetro del la función **in_array** espera un array y lo que contiene la variable **$emails** no lo es, revisa el tipo de dato que devuelve el método **BD::obtenerEmails();** o agrégalo a tu pregunta y con gusto te ayudaremos.

Comment: El tipo de dato de $emails es un array. Debido a que si hago esto me extrae todos los elementos.   $emails = BD::obtenerEmails();
 foreach ($emails as $email){
  echo $email["idemail"]."<br/>";
 }

Comment: Intenta devolver los valores, en lugar de mostrarlos `$correos = array(); foreach ($emails as $email){ $correos[] = $email["idemail"]; } return $correos;`

Comment: Los muestro en ese código del comentario para ver que sí están guardados, es decir, que el método obtenerEmails() funciona correctamente. Ahí no está el problema.

Comment: Usa `var_dump` desde el front `var_dump($emails)` para un mejor detalle

Comment: Te está regresando un objeto std class, intenta con esto
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476876/how-do-i-convert-an-object-to-an-array

Comment: No me da fallos de compilación pero no me valora bien el if

Comment: Y cuando tengas 2000 usuarios, seguiras buscando en el array? porque no haces la comprobacion en una bbdd??

Comment: Cierto es. ¿Te refieres a hacer la búsqueda y comprobación, es decir, la llamada a la función obtenerEmails() dentro de la función insertarCliente()?

Comment: @GDP He editado el código para que en lugar de que me devuelva un objecto, lo haga siendo un array. ¿A qué se debe mi error? Siempre me entra en el fichero si.php (exista o no exista en la bbdd el email).

Answer (score 2):

El problema se debe a que tu función `obtenerEmails` está devolviendo un array de arrays, de la forma `array( array('idemail' => xx), array('idemail' => yy), ...)`. Manteniendo tu código, la forma más sencilla de solucionarlo es cambiar la función así:

```
static public function obtenerEmails(){
    //Realizamos la consulta.
    $ejecucion = self::Conexion();
    $sql = "SELECT idemail FROM clientes;";
    $registro = $ejecucion->query($sql);
    //Creamos una array de emails.
    $emails = array();
    //Mientras haya email los guardamos...
    while($email = $registro->fetch()){
        //Array asociativo: al array $emails le pasamos el email concreto.
        array_push($emails, $email['idemail']);
    }
    //Devolvemos el array de emails.
    return $emails;
}
```

Sin embargo, también podrías desplazar el test a la BdDD directamente, cambiando a esto:

```
static public function mailExists($email) {
   $ejecucion = self::Conexion();
   $sql = "SELECT idemail FROM clientes WHERE idemail = ?";
   $stmt = $ejecucion->prepare($sql);
   $stmt->bind_param("e", $email);
   $stmt->execute();
   return ($stmt->get_results())->num_rows!==0;
}
```

Esta función (no testada, podría tener algún bug) debería devolver un booleano, verdadero si el mail ya existe en la base de datos y falso si no. Utiliza declaraciones preparadas para mayor seguridad.

Comment: Si quiero añadir un alert en plan "ventana emergente" con PHP, ¿habría una forma de realizarlo? Mensaje: "Cliente (no) guardado correctamente". Por ejemplo en java es con JOptionPane

Comment: PHP es un lenguaje servidor. No interactúa directamente con el PC del usuario, sólo puede enviarle datos. Sin embargo, sería posible, mediante PHP, crear código HTML que, junto con un CSS apropiado, tuviese aspecto de popup. Otra opción sería hacer el test en Javascript, via una llamada al código PHP. Javascript es un lenguaje interpretado directamente en el navegador, lo que permitiría lanzar el popup en tiempo real. En cualquier caso, son problemas complejos y distintos del de esta pregunta.